# Context dependent keyword color (listings). Question regarding (ab)using "otherkeywords"

Tags: listings

I found it difficult to phrase this question *briefly*. Therefore I will try to construct it in such a way that I at least ask it *clearly*.

**My question is specific to**: "otherkeywords" in the LaTeX package: "listings".

---

**The background for my question is:** I tried to create a rule to syntax highlight code (*the* language is not important today, I want a principle/"proof of concept"). Specifically, I want to emphasise the difference between variables, functions and methods.  The reason is that they may have *the same name* (e.g. a global function, a class method and a class constant).

Consider the following imaginary language where "print" clearly has three different meanings.

```
print 'HelloWorld'
my_class.print()
my_class::print
```

My solution produces the LaTeX output shown below (this illustrates my idea of "different meaning, same name"). I stumbled over the somewhat satisfactory, but obviously hacked, solution when I *first* defined ".print" and "::print" as "otherkeywords" and *later* used "more keywords" to redefine them in a different "classoffset". The problem is that I cannot cannot explain why this produced the output I wanted (see `\lstdefinestyle` in the LaTeX code for language definition).

[image: Output from LaTeX]

---

**My questions are:**

1. Is "otherkeywords" always linked to the lowest "classoffset", and if so, is it merely an extension of "keywords"?
2. Why can I use ".print" and "::print" in "morekeywords" after defining them in "otherkeywords"? (My logic dictates that "." and ":" should still  be "other" characters.)

---

**For anyone interested in retracing my steps:**

Produce the output shown earlier by using the LaTeX file below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings}

% Define Dummy (empty) language
\makeatletter
\lst@definelanguage{prettyprint}%
{%
}[keywords]
\makeatother

\lstdefinestyle{PRETTYPRINT}{
  language=prettyprint,%
  classoffset=0,%
    keywordstyle=\color{red!70!brown}\ttfamily,%
    morekeywords={print},%
    otherkeywords={.print,::print},%
  classoffset=1,%
    keywordstyle=\color{cyan!80!black}\ttfamily,%
    morekeywords={.print},%        
  classoffset=2,%
    keywordstyle=\color{orange!90!black}\ttfamily,%
    morekeywords={::print},%
}

\lstnewenvironment{print}{%
  \lstset{style=PRETTYPRINT}
}{}


\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
This is a hack...
\begin{print}
print 'HelloWorld'
my_class.print()
my_class::print()
\end{print}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for following to the bitter end. If you have answers to my questions, ideas for an alternative approach or any other pointers/comments, please leave a comment.

*Two a side notes: 
I have read the documentation and I am aware that I am **not** supposed to use a keyword in more than one list. 
Also, I am "dead set" on using the listings package even though I know there are alternatives.*

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the world of `listings`, there are mainly three kinds of characters: **letter**, **digit**, and **other**. (It is not pronounce or adjective, but a class named **o**-**t**-**h**-**e**-**r** literally.) The manual says that all keywords (should) consist of a letter followed by alpha-numeric characters. That is to say that `ab`, `a2` are good keywords and that `12`, `1b`, `1?`, `a?`, `!b`, `!2`, and `!?` are **not** keywords.

So, what makes **other**s so special? An answer is that **other**s are used to separate tokens. In your example, we recognize `print` as a method/function because it is separated by `.`/`::` and `()`. Otherwise if `.` and `:` were **letter**s we can only see two tokens, namely `my_class.print()` and `my_class::print`.

In this example, only the second `bar` is bold because `listings` sets `alsoletter={.},` for `[5.0]Lua`.

[image]

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language={[5.0]Lua},morekeywords={bar}]
    foo.bar
    foo:bar
\end{lstlisting}
```

But sometimes we really need to color such symbols. So `listings` allows one to write `otherkeywords={=>}`. Notice that the second `bar` is still bold --- because `listings` still regards `=` as **other**.

[image]

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language={Haskell},morekeywords={bar}]
    foo=>bar
    foo<=bar
\end{lstlisting}
```

But `otherkeywords` does not support **class number**. In your example,

> ```
> classoffset=2,
> keywordstyle=\hakuna,
> morekeywords={matata},
> ```

is equivalent to `keywordstyle=[2]\hakuna`, meaning applying `\hakuna` for all **second class keyword**, and `morekeywords=[2]{matata}`, meaning adding `matata` as a **second class keyword**.

However, as in your question 1, there is no `otherkeywords=[2]` syntax.

For question 2 it is hard to tell why **it works**. The remaining is my guess: writing `morekeywords=[3]{Aal::Izz.Well}` will make `listings` add `Aal::Izz.Well` as a **third class key word**. But `listings` will not see this keyword when parsing your code because, as I explained, **other**s separates tokens. However, `otherkeywords={Aal::Izz.Well}` forces `listings` take a look, after it reads `Aal`, at `:` and do further checks.

You may try something like:

```
\lstnewenvironment{print}{%
    \lstset{style=PRETTYPRINT}
    \tracingmacros1
    \lstset{morekeywords=[1]{Aal::Izz.Well}}
    \tracingmacros0
    \lstset{otherkeywords={Aal::Izz.Well}}
}{}
```

and found that even `otherkeywords` add the keyword to the **first class**. The latter appear to be in the **third class**. (guess why~~)

[image]